# How to join 2 neural networks in tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Suppose that by using Tensorflow, I'm able to construct to 2 functions:

`f(x ,w1)=y` (The first model- a FFNN)

`g(x, w2)=t`  (The second model - an RNN)

where: `x`, `y`, `w1` are respectively the input, output, and weights of the first model; the same goes for `x`, `t`, `w2`

My goal is to construct a hybrid model whose weights only depend on `w1` as follows:

```
g(x, f(x,w1))=t
```

To achieve that, I think the solution is to make the computational graph consider the weights `w2` as a function of `x` and `w1`.

This is where I'm stuck. How can I solve it?

*P/s* : I do agree that reimplementing RNNcell is also a solution, but I'm looking for a more witty one. Because the reimplementation demands more lines of codes and we know the motto 'the fewer code, the fewer bugs'. Furthermore, that solution makes it more complicated to use many useful methods like Dropout, Bidirectional

Comment: Replacing w2 with y should do?

Comment: How you do that with RNN constructors in Tensorflow? While it's possible with ConvLayer because Tensorflows provides some useful methods, it's not the same for RNN.